# How do I create a Typescript (1.8) Type Definition for a module that replaces the "exports" object?

Tags: node.js, module, typescript, definitelytyped

I am trying to create a type definition for a module that replaces module.exports with an anonymous function. So, the module code does this:

```
module.exports = function(foo) { /* some code */}
```

To use the module in JavaScript (Node) we do this:

```
const theModule = require("theModule");
theModule("foo");
```

I've written a .d.ts file that does this:

```
export function theModule(foo: string): string;
```

I can then write a TypeScript file like this:

```
import {theModule} from "theModule";
theModule("foo");
```

When I transpile into JavaScript, I get:

```
const theModule_1 = require("theModule");
theModule_1.theModule("foo");
```

I am not the module author. So, I **can not change the module code.**

How do I write my type definition so that it transpiles correctly to:

```
const theModule = require("theModule");
theModule("foo");
```

---

**EDIT:** For clarity, based upon the correct answer, my final code looks like this:

*the-module.d.ts*

```
declare module "theModule" {
    function main(foo: string): string;
    export = main;
}
```

*the-module-test.ts*

```
import theModule = require("theModule");
theModule("foo");
```

which will transpile to *the-module-test.js*

```
const theModule = require("theModule");
theModule("foo");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Node-style modules that export a function, [use `export =`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html#function-as-an-module)

```
function theModule(foo: string): string;
export = theModule;
```